# How do I cast properly a boolean layer in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lambda, casting, keras

I am working with some custom layers and having problems with the shape of them, when I work with it separately it works, but when I load the model to use in another one as a layer, it doesn't work anymore. Here is my layers definition:

```
def signumTransform(x):
    """
    SIGNUM function
    if positive 1
    if negative -1
    """
    import keras.backend
    return keras.backend.sign(x)

def logical_or_layer(x):
    """Processing an OR operation"""
    import keras.backend
    #normalized to 0,1 
    aux_array = keras.backend.sign(x)
    aux_array = keras.backend.relu(aux_array)
    # OR operation
    aux_array = keras.backend.any(aux_array)
    # casting back the True/False to 1,0
    aux_array = keras.backend.cast(aux_array, dtype='float32')
    return aux_array


#this is the input tensor
inputs = Input(shape=(inputSize,), name='input')

#this is the Neurule layer
x = Dense(neurulesQt, activation='softsign', name='neurules')(inputs)
#after each neuron layer, the outputs need to be put into SIGNUM (-1 or 1)
x = Lambda(signumTransform, output_shape=lambda x:x, name='signumAfterNeurules')(x)

#separating into 2 (2 possible outputs)
layer_split0 = Lambda( lambda x: x[:, :11], output_shape=[11], name='layer_split0')(x)
layer_split1 = Lambda( lambda x: x[:, 11:20], output_shape=[9], name='layer_split1')(x)
#this is the OR layer
y_0 = Lambda(logical_or_layer, output_shape=[1], name='or0')(layer_split0)
y_1 = Lambda(logical_or_layer, output_shape=[1], name='or1')(layer_split1)

y = Lambda(lambda x: K.stack([x[0], x[1]]),output_shape=[2],  name="output")([y_0, y_1])
```

Until the `layer_split` everything works properly, but in my `y_0` and `y_1` I need to do an OR operation with `keras.backend.any()`, as a return I receive a boolean so I cast it back with `keras.backend.cast()`.

If I use the Model as it is here described, it works...it compiles, can be validated and so on, but if I try to save it and load it, it simply loses one dimension, the batch dimension (`None`). The output in the summary is shown as `(None, 2)`, but when used as a layer and concatenated with another one, it shows `(2,)` and an error is thrown:

`InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'merging_layer_10/concat' (op: 'ConcatV2') with input shapes: [?,16], [2], [].`

How should I properly cast it in the `logical_or_layer` function? Should I change the `output_shape` in the Lambda Layer?

Comment: try  `y = Concatenate( axis = -1, name = "output")([y_0,y_1])`

Comment: just changed a little yours to `y = concatenate(inputs=[y_0, y_1], axis = -1, name = "output")` and tried here, but this error is thrown `InvalidArgumentError: Can't concatenate scalars (use tf.stack instead) for 'output_2/concat' (op: 'ConcatV2') with input shapes: [], [], [].`